# Sumar variables de diferentes forms - C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, variables

Tengo 3 forms distintos, y en cada form individual tengo declarada una variable int de tipo pública. Lo que necesito es que en el 3er form pueda sumar los resultados de los forms anteriores junto con el 3ero.

Es decir, en *Basico* tengo *public int res1;*

En *Diversificado* tengo *public int res2;*

Y lo mismo para el *Universitario*

Ejemplo:

**Form Basico**

```
private void ResBasico_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resultado1 = p1p + p2p + p3p;
            MessageBox.Show("Puntos obtenidos: " + resultado1);
            Form inicio = new FormInicio();
            inicio.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
```

**Form Diversificado**

```
private void ResDiv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //resultado
        {
            resultado2 = p1f + p2f + p3f;
            MessageBox.Show("Total de puntos: " + resultado2);
            Form inicio = new FormInicio();
            inicio.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
```

**Form Universitario**

```
private void ResUniv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resultado3 = rm1 + rm2 + rm3;
            MessageBox.Show("Su resultado es: " + resultado3);
            /* + resultadototal*/
        }
```

Y lo que yo necesito es que en la variable *resultadototal* pueda sumar los valores que se almacenaron en *resultado1, resultado2* y *resultado3*.

Comment: Hola, pon algo de código de los `forms` para poder entenderlo mejor.

Comment: crea una interface que añada la funcionalidad de escucha de eventos cuando ingreses los datos a cada uno de tus forms y los persista de alguna forma, luego recuperas estos datos y los sumas cuando quieras

Comment: Listo, ya es más específico.

Comment: Los nombres Basico, Diversificado y Universitario son los nombres de la **Clase** de los forms?, o sea `public partial class Basico : Form { }`

Comment: Son los nombres de los forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar variables **estáticas** en tus **Forms**, para para acceder a ellas desde cualquier sitio.

En tu caso sería así:

```
// PRIMER FORM //
public partial class Basico : Form
{
    // VARIABLE ESTÁTICA
    public static int resultado1;

    private void ResBasico_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        resultado1 = p1p + p2p + p3p;
        MessageBox.Show("Puntos obtenidos: " + resultado1);
        Form inicio = new FormInicio();
        inicio.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}

// SEGUNDO FORM //
public partial class Diversificado: Form
{
    // VARIABLE ESTÁTICA
    public static int resultado2;

    private void ResDiv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //resultado
    {
        resultado2 = p1f + p2f + p3f;
        MessageBox.Show("Total de puntos: " + resultado2);
        Form inicio = new FormInicio();
        inicio.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}

// TERCER FORM //
public partial class Universitario : Form
{
    // VARIABLE ESTÁTICA
    public static int resultado3;

    private int resultadototal;

    private void ResUniv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        resultado3 = rm1 + rm2 + rm3;
        MessageBox.Show("Su resultado es: " + resultado3);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////// Aquí la suma de los anteriores ////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        resultadototal = Basico.resultado1 +
                         Diversificado.resultado2 +
                         resultado3;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: @OscarAnibal: De nada. Recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han ayudado a solucionar tu pregunta.

Comment: @OscarAnibal: Observa también que he sustituido en la respuesta `this.resultado3` por `resultado3`. Con `this` no te iba a funcionar.

Comment: Utilicé el ```this``` y me funcionó de igual forma, ¿Me recomiendas quitarlo del todo?

Comment: @OscarAnibal si te funcionó lo puedes dejar, aunque yo lo quitaría. No vas a tener conflicto dentro del Form con otras variables o propiedades con el mismo nombre.